# How to get a subview of a UITableViewCell to extend outside of the cell's bounds

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell that looks like the following :

[image: cell picture 1]

The white textbox here basically functions like google autocomplete. So when the user starts typing something, another tableview extends from the bottom of the textfield with up to 5 autocomplete results.

So I have a tableviewcell that has another tableview within it's content view. The nested tableview has a height of 0 until the user begins searching then it grows to show up to 5 results. I want the nested tableview to be able to grow outside of its parent view, but it is getting clipped.

The tableview with the autocomplete results is being cutoff at the edge of the tableview cell. I've tried settings clips subviews and clips to bounds  properties of just about everything to NO and it's still not displaying outside of the cell's content view.

This is what's happening :

[image: cell picture 2]

There are 4 more results that I can scroll to after France, but the nested tableview is clearly being cutoff by the next tableview cell below it.

Ive set: tableviewcell's contentview clips subviews to NO, main tableviews clips subviews is set to NO, and the nested tableview's clips to bounds is set to NO.

Is it possible to get this nested tableview to be able to grow outside of its parent view (cell.contentview)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make it grow outside the cell's bounds (via `clipsToBounds = NO`), but the fact that it's outside its superview's bounds will make it impossible for the user to tap any cell.

You could do two things:

1. Make the cell grow enough so that the user can actually tap the cells inside the table view.
2. Add the results table view to your view controller's view (ie. where the original table is) and align it to the textfield in the cell. That way it'll be clickable and completely visible.

Comment: I would recommend option #2. But also ensure that you intelligently handle taps or scrolling outside the text view and results view. What happens if the user scrolls while the results view is shown? OP could either allow the results view to remain fixed to the cell, close the results view when scrolling begins, or disable scrolling until the results view is closed. It's a UX decision at that point.

Comment: Yes I am thinking of doing the 2nd option, but was hoping there would be a way to have it contained in the tableviewcell because I would like the results tableview to scroll with the main table view (and to keep the logic contained in the custom cell). If I add it to the view controller with the original table, it will be in a static location. I guess I will have to turn off scrolling of the main tableview while the results table is visible. Thanks

Comment: Craig Otis has a good point. Either make sure you detect scrolling in the outer tableview and dismiss the options table view, or correct the tableview's position to make it scroll with it. (I'd go with the first, to make it disappear like a UIPopover).

Answer (score 0):

an easier way is add the search result table on the tableview to which the above cell belongs, populate the search table based on the text entered by the user. the origin of this table depends on the textview's cell in which the user is typing.. hide/unhide this search table based on textview didstartediting/end editing..